# Checking duplicates, sum them and delete one row after summing

Tags: r, duplicates, rows

I have a dataframe which contains some duplicates. I want to sum rows of two columns where there is a duplicate and then delete the unwanted row.

Here is an example of the data,

```
Year    ID  Lats     Longs      N   n   c_id
2015    200 30.5417 -20.5254    150 30  4142
2015    200 30.5417 -20.5254    90  50  4142
```

I want to sum columns N and n into one row. the rest of the information i.e. Lats , Longs , ID and Year is to remain the same e.g.,

```
Year    ID  Lats    Long        N   n   c_id
2015    200 30.5417 -20.5254    240 80  4142
```

Comment: duplicates with the same c_id like 4142 in the above case. c_id is what uniquely identifies each record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
df <- structure(list(year = c(2015, 2015), ID = c(200, 200), Lats = c(30.5417, 
            30.5417), Longs = c(-20.5254, -20.5254), N = c(150, 90), n = c(30, 
            50), c_id = c(4142, 4142)), .Names = c("year", "ID", "Lats", 
            "Longs", "N", "n", "c_id"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
            class = "data.frame")
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="c_id,year,ID,Lats,Longs"]

   c_id year  ID    Lats    Longs   N  n
1: 4142 2015 200 30.5417 -20.5254  240 80
```

Solution using `plyr`:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(c_id, year, ID, Lats, Longs), function(x) c(N=sum(x$N), n=sum(x$n)))

  c_id year  ID    Lats    Longs   N  n
1 4142 2015 200 30.5417 -20.5254 240 80
```

Comment: Am trying to understand this code. i have 9222 records, can this work with this number of records?

Comment: +1 Btw, instead of `by=c("c_id", "year", "ID", "Lats", "Longs")` there's a shortcut: `by="c_id,year,ID,Lats,Longs"`. Comma separated names are just for column names only, though, no expressions.

Comment: Great. Also why wrap the result with `as.data.frame`?  Was that just to make it identical to the result from plyr?  If so, think it's ok to return a data.table, which is a data.frame too, otherwise newbies might get the impression they really do have to convert the result back to data.frame, which would indeed be a pain.

Comment: Hi, am trying the data.table option and i get this error Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object ' YeStart' not found

Comment: IDS[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="cid, YeStart, Cluster_ID, Lat, Long"]

Comment: > names(IDS)
[1] "YeStart"    "Cluster_ID" "Lat"        "Long"       "Ex"         "pfpr"       "cid"       
> 
It works when i encolose " ", but shows results of the first and last five.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22180/discussion-between-jonestats-and-arun)

Comment: @jonestats Don't put spaces when comma separating. It's looking for " YeStart" (with a space at the start). data.table allows, maintains and likes spaces and other special characters in column names.

Comment: @Matthew, the problem was that he was working on the `data.frame`. He did not convert it to a `data.table`. Its resolved now. Pardon me. I forgot to write back here that its resolved.